# What kind of primary key is this?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Here is the id

```
DIAK6c
```

and another

```
65d0a2
```

The first id came from wahoha.com and the second came from webanswers.com. How can I produce an ID like this in my database. I have mysql with asp.net c#

Comment: Looks like an identifier of some sort. Why do you think these map to primary keys in a database?

Comment: When you say "primary key" I think you actually mean "artificial identifier". Whether the identifier is (solely) used as a key is secondary and whether that key is primary for a given table is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most probably an integer number encoded to that form using a reversible algorithm, one simple way to achieve that is to convert your numeric id from base 10 to base 36:

```
CONV( 5234525977, 10, 36 )
```

result would be '2EKI23D' which you can easily convert back to integer form:

```
CONV( '2EKI23D', 36, 10 )
```

result: 5234525977

Answer (score 1):

Try out: (10 random digits like `6422ab8810`)

```
SELECT LEFT(MD5(RAND()), 10)
```

To have sucn an Id you have to use string data type what is really not the best option from performance perspectives (index rebuild speed degrades). So rethink 10 times before using such an Id as Primary Key.

This could be some kind of extra Id in addition to main RowId which is `INT PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: It isn't necessarily being _stored_ in a string.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways, you can either keep integer identifiers in the database and convert to character combinations when you expose them, or create character combinations (by random, hashing, permutations, et.c.) to use as keys in the database.

The second example looks like hexadecimal representation, that can easilty be created from an integer key:

```
int id = 6672546;
string idString = Convert.ToString(id, 16);
```